# MySQL join poor performance

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I'm trying to select related content based on the same taxonomy_index ID, but are struggeling with slow queries.

First try (very poor performance):

```
    SELECT n.nid, n.created, title, 5 AS rel 
FROM taxonomy_index ti1 
    JOIN taxonomy_index ti2 ON ti1.tid = ti2.tid AND ti2.nid != 235884
    INNER JOIN node n on ti2.nid = n.nid 
WHERE ti1.nid = NAME_CONST('nid',235884) 
    AND (`type` = 'np_news' OR `type` = 'blog_indl_g') 
    AND n.created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
GROUP BY ti2.nid HAVING count(*) = 3 
LIMIT 10;
```

[Query 1 explained](http://npinvestor.dk/graphics/tmp/query1_explain.png)

Second try (poor performance):

```
SELECT n.nid, n.created, title, 5 AS rel  from taxonomy_index ti
    INNER JOIN node n on ti.nid = n.nid
WHERE tid IN (SELECT td.tid FROM taxonomy_index ti inner join taxonomy_term_data td on ti.tid = td.tid WHERE ti.nid = 297621 AND td.vid in (5,11) AND `name` != '')
    AND (`type` = 'np_news' OR `type` = 'blog_indl_g')  
    AND n.created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
GROUP BY ti.nid
HAVING count(*) = 3
LIMIT 10;
```

[Query 2 explained](http://npinvestor.dk/graphics/tmp/query2_explain.png)

Hmm i still don't know why it is so slow! The sub select performs great and returns 3 tid's: 785,786,792.

Third try: (Good performance):

```
SELECT n.nid, n.created, title, 5 AS rel  from taxonomy_index ti
    INNER JOIN node n on ti.nid = n.nid
WHERE tid IN (785,786,792)
    AND (`type` = 'np_news' OR `type` = 'blog_indl_g')  
    AND n.created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
GROUP BY ti.nid
HAVING count(*) = 3
LIMIT 10;
```

The third one actually seems to perform quite OK, but it does not do the job, because the id's are static. 
How can I optimise this?

Note* I cannot post link to explain of the third query.

Comment: To optimize a query, **we need to see the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: Also providing the results of `EXPLAIN <query>` would be useful.

Comment: And properly qualifying all columns - like you did with n.nid,n.created - would help us too.

Comment: I have updated the question. Seems like i join too many rows, but i'm not sure how to limit this.